# How do I set up my logging service in an aspnetcore application before initializing the aspnetcore application itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

When creating an aspnetcore application, we are usually provided with a standard and a pretty straightforward template for the app -- we have our `Program` class like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

and our `Startup` class to configure the aspnetcore app.

I am in a situation, where I have to run an aspnetcore app while not following this pattern. I have my `Startup` class as usual, and I have my logic in place to create the host builder and my concept works fine. The only thing that I am missing is that I need the logging capabilities of the aspnetcore app to be ready before creating the host builder.

I want to use the built-in logging functionality provided by Microsoft, as well as I want it to respect my configuration settings for the logging levels, but I want to log a few things before creating the host builder and running the aspnetcore app. Furthermore, I would prefer the aspnetcore app to re-use that logging service (I believe I can inject it as a service there once I find a way to initialize the logging itself). Below is an example of the way my `Main` method needs to work:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ILogger logger = ... // I need to figure out how to get a ready logging instance here

    var hostBuilder = DoSomeSpecificStuffAndCreateHostBuilder(logger, args);
   
    hostBuilder.Build().Run();
}
```

Any suggestions and clues are welcome.

Comment: See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-during-host-construction)

Comment: @PeterBons, very close to my requirements, except that I need this before instantiating the host builder, hence I am a little bit cut-off by using its logging service. Maybe I can create a fake host builder just to get my logger service, and then make my actual app and host builder use the logger that I created -- not really sure how elegant as a solution this is though

Comment: Deleted my answer in order to keep your question open. Last comment: Serilog is adressing the issue: nblumhardt.com/2020/10/bootstrap-logger Scroll down to CreateBootstrapLogger

Comment: @RoarS. I hope that will be able to verify this approach tomorrow and will let you know if the serilog approach helps me. I prefer to write my own solution so I won't get coupled to a particular logging framework but you already pointed a few good ideas to me. I will ping you back if I succeed so you can revert the answer and probably edit it a little with what helped me. If I succeed you also deserve some credit for it.